# Classifying availablility based on months available and identifiers - Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data set with identifiers (3 digit district code_2 digit country code_10 digit code) and the month number (1 to 12) with data available. The identifier will repeat for every month available on separate rows. For example if this identifier "LAX_CN_0000000000" had 3 months of data, it would list the identifier 3 times with the corresponding months available. I want to classify these identifiers based on the months available. For example, I have:

```
Identifier_Column             Month_Column
LAX_CN_0000000000             1
IAH_MY_1111111111             10 
LAX_CN_0000000000             2
LAX_CN_0000000000             3
IAH_MY_1111111111             8
```

I would like to see:

```
    Identifier_Column      Month_Column    Classification
    LAX_CN_0000000000      1               In sequence but not all 12 months
    IAH_MY_1111111111      10              > 2 month but not in order
    LAX_CN_0000000000      2               In sequence but not all 12 months
    LAX_CN_0000000000      3               In sequence but not all 12 months
    IAH_MY_1111111111      8               > 2 month but not in order
```

So there would be 4 different types of classification:

```
1. All 12 months available
2. Only 1 month available
3. In sequence but not all 12 months
4. > 2 month but not in order
```

Comment: you should include what you've done so far to attempt this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***setup***
included some additional cases

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        Idetifier_Column=[id1] + [id2] + [id1] * 2 + [id3] * 12 + [id4] * 12,
        Month_Column=[1, 10, 2, 3] + list(range(1, 13)) + list(range(12, 0, -1))
    )
)
```

***helper functions***
there is probably a better way to check if sorted

```
def is_sorted(x):
    return (np.arange(len(x)) == np.argsort(x)).all() * 1

def how_many(x):
    n = len(np.unique(x))
    return 1 if n == 1 else 2 if n < 12 else 3
```

***map the tuples I'll create to descriptive strings***

```
class_map = {
    (1, 1): "Only 1 month available",
    (2, 1): "In sequence but not all 12 months",
    (2, 0): "> 2 month but not in order",
    (3, 1): "All 12 months available",
    (3, 0): "All 12 months available out of order",
}
```

***magic***

```
grpby = df.groupby('Idetifier_Column').Month_Column
df['Classification'] = \
    df.Idetifier_Column.map(
      # |<------------- creating tuples -------------->|
        grpby.agg([how_many, is_sorted]).apply(tuple, 1).map(class_map))
```

---

```
print(df)

     Idetifier_Column  Month_Column                        Classification
0   LAX_CN_0000000000             1     In sequence but not all 12 months
1   IAH_MY_1111111111            10                Only 1 month available
2   LAX_CN_0000000000             2     In sequence but not all 12 months
3   LAX_CN_0000000000             3     In sequence but not all 12 months
4   SFO_MY_2222222222             1               All 12 months available
5   SFO_MY_2222222222             2               All 12 months available
6   SFO_MY_2222222222             3               All 12 months available
7   SFO_MY_2222222222             4               All 12 months available
8   SFO_MY_2222222222             5               All 12 months available
9   SFO_MY_2222222222             6               All 12 months available
10  SFO_MY_2222222222             7               All 12 months available
11  SFO_MY_2222222222             8               All 12 months available
12  SFO_MY_2222222222             9               All 12 months available
13  SFO_MY_2222222222            10               All 12 months available
14  SFO_MY_2222222222            11               All 12 months available
15  SFO_MY_2222222222            12               All 12 months available
16  SEA_CN_3333333333            12  All 12 months available out of order
17  SEA_CN_3333333333            11  All 12 months available out of order
18  SEA_CN_3333333333            10  All 12 months available out of order
19  SEA_CN_3333333333             9  All 12 months available out of order
20  SEA_CN_3333333333             8  All 12 months available out of order
21  SEA_CN_3333333333             7  All 12 months available out of order
22  SEA_CN_3333333333             6  All 12 months available out of order
23  SEA_CN_3333333333             5  All 12 months available out of order
24  SEA_CN_3333333333             4  All 12 months available out of order
25  SEA_CN_3333333333             3  All 12 months available out of order
26  SEA_CN_3333333333             2  All 12 months available out of order
27  SEA_CN_3333333333             1  All 12 months available out of order
```

Comment: So I tried this and got "Only 1 month available" for every record in my data set. Also sorry for not being clear enough but you have "All 12 months available out of order" as an option. Instead of that I wanted something like "Greater than 2 months but not in order". Meaning it has a least 2 months available and less than 12 months available but has a break in sequence (let me further explain with examples):

Comment: Classification Options:
#1. All 12 months (1 to 12)
#2. 1 Month (any month from 1 to 12)
#3. Sequential Months but not all 12 months. Examples 1,2,3 or 11,12 or 2,3,4,5,6
#4. Has more than 2 months but less that 12 and if a sequence is present, it breaks at some point. Examples 1,2,3,5 or 1,12 or 4,5,6,8,9,10

Comment: @Brian The one thing I'll point out is that I wanted to add an option that wasn't covered in the set of options you presented.  If I got that wrong... my bad.  However, if it isn't obvious how to adapt this to your specific needs then there is a bigger problem.  This is not intended to deliver a snippet for you to copy and paste (yes! I hear what I'm saying.  I know this is SO where that is the norm).  Instead, I believe that I've shown enough to demonstrate how you can do this.  If there are small gaps, you should feel empowered to fill them in.  And even update us with what you did.

Comment: I don't understand what each part of your code is doing well enough. Maybe some more explanation of what each block of code is doing would be helpful.